# PHP custom encoding function is not giving required result

Tags: php, algorithm, character-encoding

I am trying to write a function in PHP in such a way that it converts a string into encoded one according to the given offset.

For example:
if the offset is `2` and input is `c` then the output will be `e`
similarly if the offset is `5` and input is `X` then the output is `c`

```
function encode($char,$offset)
{
 $char_list = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
 $_offset = strpos($char_list,$char) + $offset;

 if($offset > strlen($char_list )){
  $_offset = _$offset  - $offset;
 }
 return $char_list[$_offset];
}
```

Required results:

```
encode("a",0) // must returns a
encode("c",5) // must returns h
encode("X",9) // must returns g
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: @Twinfriends, fix the algorithm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Caesar cipher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177443/php-caesar-cipher)

Comment: It is not duplicate of the link you posted.

Comment: Instead of `if ....`, do `$_offset = $_offset  % strlen($char_list);`

Comment: Please update your question by adding what's the current result and what's exactly is wrong.

Comment: `$_offset = _$offset  - $offset;` why there's `_$offset` instead of `$_offset`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculation of the new offset inside the `if` block is incorrect, you should subtract the length of the string, not the offset. But it is better to use the [modulo operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php):

```
function encode($char,$offset) {
    $char_list = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $_offset = strpos($char_list,$char) + $offset;
    $_offset = $_offset % strlen($char_list);
    return $char_list[$_offset];
}
```

Comment: Can you little bit explain what the % sign does here?

Comment: It is the [modulo operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php), so whenever the value at the left is greater than the value at the right, it is reduced by the right value until it is smaller than the value at the right. Otherwise put, it is the remainder after an integer division.